# How can i use a different shell in Emacs Shell?

Tags: shell, shell-mode, bash, zsh

I am currently using Zsh in my regular terminal app on my Mac OS X. However, it's heavily customized and colors don't appear properly inside Emacs. So I am thinking, I should probably use `shell-mode` with a different `zshrc` or use "Bash" as the default shell in `shell-mode`.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide more details about what problems your zsh config actually causes? Descriptions or even screenshots would be helpful. I assume you are using `shell` right now, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly set which shell <kbd>M-x</kbd>`shell` uses by customizing `explicit-shell-file-name`

If your zsh config causes problems with `shell` you might try <kbd>M-x</kbd> `term` or `ansi-term` instead which may play better with your config.

If nothing quite works right, you could always use tmux or screen to flip between emacs and a real shell.

Comment: Also, `C-z` is helpful under certain circumstances.

Comment: Thanks! that works. Is it possible to customize further? such as mapping Ctrl-L to clear instead of recenter window?

Comment: There may be better way to do it, but you can write a function that does `(progn (delete-region (point-min) (point-max)) (call-interactively 'comint-send-input)` which could be used to clear the shell. Then you could bind that to C-l. I have such a function here: https://github.com/jordonbiondo/.emacs.d/blob/master/jordon/jordon-fns.el#L197

Comment: @user3470707 yes, it's possible, map `Ctrl-L` to a defined function in `shell-mode` to clear.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733668/command-to-clear-shell-while-using-emacs-shell