# Specify and use inferior shell only once

Tags: shell

I know you can customize settings or set environmental variables to get emacs to use other shells in shell-mode ([1](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20254/how-can-i-use-a-different-shell-in-emacs-shell), [2](https://masteringemacs.org/article/running-shells-in-emacs-overview)). Is it possible to simply start a shell specifying which shell you want to use interactively?

Like: `M-x other-shell RET /path/to/csh RET`

Or set up something in your init file to let you use other shells fairly easily without changing the default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to do the job:

```
(defun other-shell (explicit-shell-file-name)
  (interactive "f")
  (if (called-interactively-p)
      (call-interactively #'shell)
    (shell)))
```

This relies on `shell` using the variable `explicit-shell-file-name` as a first choice of the shell to be used.

It also relies on *not* using lexical scoping.

Comment: This works if you don't already have a shell running. But if you do, it switches you to the existing shell.

Comment: @Tyler Use a prefix argument to avoid that. No different from the original `shell` command.

Comment: To use a prefix when you have `helm-M-x` bound see this asnwer http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20299/how-to-pass-a-prefix-argument-to-helm-m-x

Comment: AFAIK lexical scoping does not matter here since `explicit-shell-file-name` is defined through `defcustom` in `shell.el` and that marks the variable as special.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Harald's answer. If you want to specify the shell by name (interactive "s" option) rather than path and use the default `shell-file-name` instead of the explicit path:

```
(defun other-shell (shell-file-name)
  (interactive "s")
  (if (called-interactively-p)
      (call-interactively #'shell)
    (shell)))
```

I found this to be more useful when using a shell like `xonsh` where I just want to use the one in the virtualenv that started emacs, rather than specify long explicit paths.

Comment: FYI: Also for this version of `other-shell` lexical scoping does not matter since `(special-variable-p 'shell-file-name)` gives t.